# Android - `onInitFinished` method is not callled in Branch.io

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I am new in branch.io and i am following their official documentation. when i run my application `onInitFinished` method is not called. i had found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42852550/banch-oninitfinished-not-called-even-after-timeout) but a term `postBranchInitSession(null);` used in the solution which is unknown to me and i tried to find out but did not get anything. on its official documentation there is very confusing documentation, from that documentation i am not getting something

here is my code:

```
  try {
        branch = Branch.getInstance();
        branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    Log.d("Splash onStart", referringParams.toString());

                } else {
                    Log.i("MyApp", error.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After checking so many Questions and solutions on `StackOverFlow` and other sites i have solved this problem by adding  `android:name="io.branch.referral.BranchApp"` in application as shown below:

```
<application
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:supportsRtl="true"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
     android:name="io.branch.referral.BranchApp">
     ...
</application>
```

as suggested [here by Alex Bauer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482405/android-branch-io-tutorial-branch-getautoinstancethis/37492429#37492429)